# on change css selector for select element

Tags: html, css

I have created a select box with custom css but the problem is that i want to make the custom arrow to downwards once you select it, so right now if i select any option the arrow will be upward, after selection if i click outside only it comes to default downward position.

Since i am using **focus** this issue comes, what is the better selector so that user clicks on select box it will be upward and once he selects it comes to normal downwards

see the sample snippet

```css
.select {
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.1);
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: green;
  background-color: #32a8a6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 7px),
    calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 7px), calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
  background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1px 1.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, gray 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, gray 50%, transparent 50%);
  font-family: ProximaNova, Arial, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.select:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, grey 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, grey 50%);
  background-position: calc(100% - 15px) 23px, calc(100% - 20px) 23px,
    calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
  background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1px 1.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: 0;
}

.select:-moz-focus {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<select class='select'>
 <option>one</option>
 <option>two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:active` pseudo class instead.

Since it can be hard to see the arrow direction in the example below when the options are showing, I've changed the background color instead to demonstrate the effect.

```css
.select {
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.1);
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: green;
  background-color: #32a8a6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 7px),
    calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 7px), calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
  background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1px 1.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, gray 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, gray 50%, transparent 50%);
  font-family: ProximaNova, Arial, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.select:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class='select'>
 <option>one</option>
 <option>two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @ cjl750 thank you for the response, one more quick question in mac when i tried to select the options it doesn't comes properly down so the effect is not visible any idea on this ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Yes, I am working on a Mac and noticed that problem. I did a little searching just now to make sure I wasn't missing something, but I believe there's nothing you can really do about that. You would have to do a totally custom dropdown that is not actually a `select` at all but more like a `span` with a `role` and click handlers on it, then your `options` would be `span` elements as well. (Not simple, I know.) `appearance: none` doesn't end up being super helpful for `select` elements exactly because of this reason – you can style the `select` but not the `option`.

Comment: so as a simple hack there is nothing much we can do isn't, Cool even i tried searching but didnt find any solution to this. Fine anyways thanks cjl750 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `.select:focus` with `.select:focus:active`

```css
.select {
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.1);
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: green;
  background-color: #32a8a6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 7px),
    calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 7px), calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
  background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1px 1.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, gray 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, gray 50%, transparent 50%);
  font-family: ProximaNova, Arial, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

.select:focus:active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, grey 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, grey 50%);
  background-position: calc(100% - 15px) 23px, calc(100% - 20px) 23px,
    calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
  background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1px 1.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: 0;
}

.select:-moz-focus {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<select class='select'>
 <option>one</option>
 <option>two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: one more quick question in mac when i tried to select the options it doesn't comes properly down so the effect is not visible any idea on this in mac the options comes above of select box as overlapped